# Converting interactive shell output to plain text

Tags: java, linux, shell, command-line

I am trying to view the temperature table for my CPU on my Linux machine with Java. This bit of code will display the shell output for other commands, `ls`, `cat file`, but will not display `watch sensors` as it returns an interactive output. Is there a way I can convert it to plain text somehow?

`Error: [/usr/bin/watch, sensors]`

`Error opening terminal: unknown.`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class tempapp{

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //build command
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("/usr/bin/watch");
    //args
    commands.add("sensors");
    System.out.println(commands);

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    pb.directory(new File("/home/ethano"));
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = pb.start();

    //Read output
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null, previous = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        if (!line.equals(previous)) {
            previous = line;
            out.append(line).append('\n');
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    //Check result
    if (process.waitFor() == 0){
        System.out.println("\n success");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //weird termination
    System.err.println(commands);
    System.err.println(out.toString());
    System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that `watch` does is call the command it is given (`sensors` in this case) once every two seconds. You can simply have your application emulate this behaviour by calling `/usr/bin/sensors` in a for-loop once every two seconds (or however many times you need), therefore omitting the need to read interactive shell output.

Comment: here i was trying to make it exponentially harder than necessary. thank you.